# Paste values in DF from a row to another in a range of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I got a big data dataframe and I want to paste values from a single row to another one.
you can check the picture and see better what I mean:

[image]
I want to replace the red color values with the blue ones (and then I can delete the red row, I don't need it anymore).
I'm using tidyverse and I've meneged to do this:

```r
mutate(question6=replace(question6, uniqueCode=="ABC14", "2"))
```

But my data is big and I have around 70 columns (which are all the last ones in the DF and standing next to each other) so I want instead of insert values one by one just copy and past by column range from a specific row to another.
I can use the column "uniqueCode" to point the specific row.

thank you for you help,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a system by which you want to replace rows with another, so for a single copy instruction, why not go with this base R code:

```
cols_to_copy <- sprintf('question%s',6:10)
df[df$uniqueCode == "ABC14",cols_to_copy] <- df[df$uniqueCode == "ABC15",cols_to_copy]
```

Wouldn't that solve your problem?

---

Update per request in comments:
to chain this into your `dplyr` pipe-flow, just wrap it in curly brackets:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  {
    cols_to_copy <- sprintf('question%s',6:10)
    .[.$uniqueCode == "ABC14",cols_to_copy] <- .[.$uniqueCode == "ABC15",cols_to_copy]
    .
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I wanted to use Tidyverse pipes for my code flow since this is a single change out of a many and takes place in the middle of my code. Is there any way to combine base R code inside pipes flow?

Comment: How do you identify which rows to change? Will you be able to put that into a list or add a column to your df?

Comment: I can use the UniqueCode which is different for each row, right?
"Get values from columns rage X:Y in row "UniqueCode = 123" and paste?

Comment: I mean, how do you know which rows to replace and which rows to use to overwrite them?

Comment: it's just one row,
I know where is it and where is should be. It's a single mistake I need to fix using R.
I'd like to identify the row by using the UniqueCode column

Comment: got it, I assumed there'd be a whole lot of instances for you to repair and you'd want a general purpose fix to it. have added a dplyr-style solution, I think that should suffice for you then

Comment: thank you so much for you help. I just realised that in the example I gave you all the columns I want to switch has the same name "QuestionX" only with different numbers. In my DF there are different column names such as "date", "Question2", "QuestionAfter", etc... There will be a problem to use sprintf in order to get all these columns, right?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite *all* columns except "uniqueCode" or just a select few?

Comment: just a selected few (but they are all the last ones) its like the last 60 ones so maybe there is a way to select "everything after the column called question4"?

Comment: sure there is. try `cols_to_copy <- which(colnames(.)=='question4'):ncol(.)` instead.